# Stop event from bubbling to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've the following situation

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

And some css

```
div:active { background-color: green }
```

Is there a preferred way, when the `#child` is clicked, to only have the `#child` getting `active`. I've tried

```
$('#child').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But whatever I do, the `#parent` also gets `active`. Note that I cannot change the CSS!

Anyway, the only solution I see is to add an `.active` class instead using `:active` but I hope it can be done somehow with event-propagation.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7cwf1yv6/)

Comment: So you just want the little square to change colour? like - https://jsfiddle.net/7cwf1yv6/2/

Comment: It seems the title of your question doesn't really reflect what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [CSS spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#active-pseudo):

> The parent of an element that matches `:active` also matches `:active`.

So no, there doesn't seem to be a way to make the parent *not* match `:active`. You either have to make your selector more specific or not use `:active`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [pseudo class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) instead of a class and thus, getting the default browser behaviour which *might be* to propagate the active status to every parents of the active element. [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) & [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) doesn't specify if it's the case

> CSS 2.1 does not define if the parent of an element that is ':active' or ':hover' is also in that state.

You probably want to set a class on your element like this :

```
$('#child').click(function (e) {
    $('#child').addClass('active');
});
```

and change your css like this

```
div.active { background-color: green }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two approaches, the second. Since, there may be more than one child. An alternative is to delegate using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), but based on your context.

**TL;DR**
event.stopPropagation(), intercept it and do your operation and you may `return false` at the end which does the same as event.stopImmediatePropagation().

---

[event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

> Cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

[event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

> Prevents further propagation of the current event.

[event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

> If several listeners are attached to the same element for the same event type, they are called in order in which they have been added. If during one such call, event.stopImmediatePropagation() is called, no remaining listeners will be called.

Hope this helps.